# c# - Ignore empty/null value and guid empty in WebApiConfig

Tags: c#

I have a controller that returns a json in a function GET. I want to ignore\delete the empty, null value and the guide empty of my json, that I sent to a third part.

In the WebApiConfig I use:
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
And it works for the null value, but not to the empty\guid.empty value.

So I try to add config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new EmptyToNullConverter()); and the class EmptyToNullConverter. To convert the empty value in null and then removed by the other command but it doesn't work because it doesn't convert the values.

the class **EmptyToNullConverter** is:

```
public class EmptyToNullConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private JsonSerializer _stringSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            string value = _stringSerializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ||  value == Guid.Empty.ToString())
            {
                value = null;
            }

            return value;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            _stringSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

    }
```

How can I do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the JSON being converted from a concrete class? Have you tried [JsonProperty("property_name",DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)] on the guid?

Comment: Thanks! I have a lot of property so i search to do this globally. I try config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore }; but it ignores all default values(bool, null ecc), even if they are true!

Comment: I thought this was only a problem with the guid?

Comment: the problem is with empty string ("") and guid.empty (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the bool value from the DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore and consider only some type?

Comment: How is your json being constructed? Is it from serializing a class? If so, you should just be able to stick this above the guid property. However, it sounds like you're wanting to do something else for some reason, so please explain why this can't be done.

Comment: Yes, I serialize a class

Answer (score 0):

Even when you are serializing if the object type is `Guid`. It still can't be null, trying to override at a serialization level could create confusion anyway as if the receiver is expecting a `Guid` in a response model. Even if you send nothing in a JSON response, their code may still initialise an empty `Guid`.

Is there any reason you couldn't use a nullable Guid? Given you are new to stack overflow i'm going to perhaps rudely assume your new to coding and so you might not be familiar with nullable value types.

Value types such as `int`, `float`, `GUID`, `DateTime` etc... will always have a default value, however you can force them to be nullable by declaring them with a question mark suffixed.

e.g.

```
int x // == 0;
int? x // == null;
Guid g // == 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;
Guid? g // == null;
```

A good general rule is that if an value type can be essentially null, then make it nullable. Then you won't need any fancy conversions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My guid can't be nullable (Guid?) because in same case they are mandatory and I use the  hereditary of the class.